screen resolution input out of range
I set my monitor at 76 hz by accident when its only capable of 60hz it displays an error (input out of range) which is expected but i cant fix this error it I pressed enter and every other key, rebooted a few times ,checked the bios to see if I can change the resolution from there but didn't find it now every time I boot up the pc it tells me this error and doesn't let me in to windows. I'm on h310 motherboard if anyone knows how to fix please tell me

Have you tried Windows Safe mode? Try booting and holding power button down for 15 seconds, and repeat three times. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win-10-how-to-reset-display-resolution-without/ae3bd064-32b7-456e-81bf-134b7318febb , https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-monitors-resolution-high-display-68388.html

Win+Ctrl+Shift+B should trigger a quick reset of your display driver, which may reinitialize the display into a default resolution that works. This works from the lock/login screen.

Other options:

Interrupting the normal Windows boot sequence 3 times in a row will trigger Automatic Repair mode. This may be tricky to time if you can't see the Windows loading screen. You can interrupt the normal booting by holding the power button until the system shuts down, flipping the PSU's on/off switch (if it has one), or removing the PC's power cable after the motherboard firmware hands the boot sequence to the Operating System. The Advanced options > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup Settings > Restart option will reboot and bring up the Startup Settings, option 3) Enable low-resolution video may work
Another way is to uninstall your graphics driver in Safe Mode, there are several ways to boot into Safe Mode

After following the above steps use option 4) Enable Safe mode
Blindly log into Windows and use the following key presses:

Win+R - Opens the Windows Run command
shutdown /r /o /t 0 - This is the command to reboot into recovery mode without waiting
Ctrl+Shift+Enter - Runs the above command with administrator privilege
← - User Account Control to "Yes"
Enter - Executes the above





